# Image transfer between client and server with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a PostgreSQL database where images are stored as bytea[]. I want to transfer these images to the ActiveMQ server and later to the client side. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a [BytesMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html).